# Why Stripe gives me this error every few hours: Network error: ConnectionError:

Tags: python, python-3.x, stripe-payments

I receive the following error every few hours. Why?

I think this is related to Stripe payment.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1348, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 316, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 285, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

During handling of the above error some other errors occur:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 400, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1348, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 316, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 285, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stripe/http_client.py", line 286, in request
    result = self._thread_local.session.request(
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/digital/paymentfollower.py", line 145, in paymentfollowing
    newer_charge=stripe.Charge.list(limit=1,ending_before=older_charge_data)
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/abstract/listable_api_resource.py", line 23, in list
    response, api_key = requestor.request("get", url, params)
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 119, in request
    rbody, rcode, rheaders, my_api_key = self.request_raw(
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 343, in request_raw
    rbody, rcode, rheaders = self._client.request_with_retries(
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stripe/http_client.py", line 151, in request_with_retries
    raise connection_error
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stripe/http_client.py", line 123, in request_with_retries
    response = self.request(method, url, headers, post_data)
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stripe/http_client.py", line 312, in request
    self._handle_request_error(e)
  File "/home/digital/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stripe/http_client.py", line 364, in _handle_request_error
    raise error.APIConnectionError(msg, should_retry=should_retry)
stripe.error.APIConnectionError: Unexpected error communicating with Stripe.  If this problem persists,
let us know at support@stripe.com.

(Network error: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

Stack-overflow keeps saying that my post is mostly code and I should add more explanation. So I keep repeating this sentence.

Stack-overflow keeps saying that my post is mostly code and I should add more explanation. So I keep repeating this sentence.

Comment: What request are you making when you get that error? Is this a Stripe API call or are you making another request?

Comment: It's in the name `ConnectionError`. The Internet is unreliable, and sometimes your request is lost on the way. It's normal that this happens now and then. You should log the error, and then retry. https://stripe.com/docs/error-handling#network-errors

Comment: But it looks like you have only included part of the traceback. This is only from the Python standard library urllib3 and http modules. But what is the calling code? Without the full traceback we cannot know if it was caused by a Stripe library or some other service that does http requests to a remote server.

Comment: @HåkenLid when this error occurs, should I reconnect? what code should I use to reconnect?

Comment: @HåkenLid I added the full stack error. Please check the post again.

Comment: @Pompey I guess this is a Stripe call. I call Stripe functions in several parts of my code. I don't know which call makes this error.

Comment: Seems like this must be your code in the traceback. You could add some error handling / logging somewhere around here: `File "/home/digital/paymentfollower.py", line 145, in paymentfollowing`

Comment: The python-stripe library also has built-in automatic retry. If you are lucky, you might solve the problem by increasing this configuration value. `stripe.max_network_retries = 2`

 https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python#configuring-automatic-retries

Comment: @HåkenLid line 145 of `File "/home/digital/paymentfollower.py"` is this: `newer_charge=stripe.Charge.list(limit=1,ending_before=older_charge_data)` what error handling I can add to make Stripe reconnect and don't give error?

Comment: @HåkenLid I guess `stripe.max_network_retries = 2` fixed the issue. So please write an answer so that I select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stripe.max_network_retries = 2` fixed the issue for me, as was suggested in the comments.